# Double-click DataGridView row using sql server?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

When I Double Click On Row I am facing this error.How Can Resolve this issue help me and sorry for English

[image]

Thanks In Advance

Comment: maybe selRow is nothing

Comment: please add a [mcve]. I'm *really* interested how SQL Server can intereact with winforms app.

Answer (score 0):

Never post pictures of code. We can't copy it and try it out. It works for me with a bit of change.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick
    Dim aa = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value
    Dim selRow = dt.Select($"ID = {aa}")
    TextBox1.Text = selRow(0)("Type")
End Sub
```

I have a field called ID and a field called Type in the DataTable I am testing with. I think that .Item of a DataRow wants an ordinal so I just used the default which accepts a string.